# How can you change the index of multiple array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing, fetch

**Problem:**

How can you **change the index** of **multiple objects** within an array of 100 objects?
In my case I would like to push them to the end of the array.

I have fetched a json array that contains over 100 objects, each with their own properties including a number property for each object that can be used to filter.

**Attempts**

- I tried populating a variable using .splice to remove the specific array objects. Although .push wont accept that variable.
- Also tried .slice but couldn't push the sliced objects to the end.
- Also tried to loop through the original array using a for loop and an if statement with the condition of each objects "number" property.

**Code:**
(the fetch is a success, only issue is the restructure of the array itself)

```
elementsArray.value = await data.json();

let removedElements = elementsArray.value.slice(56,71);

elementsArray.value.push(removedElements);
```

Comment: To append them to the end you need to use `.concat`, not `.push`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With `slice`, the original array will not be modified. Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead.
2. `push` accepts one or more elements. so use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant']

const removedElements = animals.splice(2, 2)

animals.push(...removedElements)

// some other alternatives
// Array.prototype.push.apply(animals, removedElements)
// animals.concat(removedElements)

console.log(animals)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can use splice to append a to b  but as in the commentarys mentioned for this use case `.concat()` or `.push(...otherArray)` is the better choice

```js
let a = [1,2,3],
    b = [4,5,6];
    a.splice(0, 0, ...b);
    
    console.log(a);
```